# SDL_CreateWindowFrom vs SDL_DestroyWindow X11 error SDL2

Tags: error-handling, x11, sdl-2, display

I get a window ID from the command line, and create an SDL window with it:

```
Window window_id = from_cli();    // e.g. 0x34000c8
w = SDL_CreateWindowFrom((void*) (Window) window_id);
```

When my program finishes I try to clean up:

```
SDL_DestroyWindow(w);
```

And that is when I got an X11 error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x34000c8
  Serial number of failed request:  255
  Current serial number in output stream:  256
```

Obviously, the caller of my program - which I cannot change - has already destroyed the X window I was using.

---

How should I handle this situation?

1. `SDL_DestroyWindow()` can be omitted if the SDL window was created with `SDL_CreateWindowFrom()`
2. go for `SDL_SysWMinfo`, pick up `x11.display`, create my own X11 error handler, and filter errors for `window_id`?

---

Looking at the SDL2-2.0.9 source code, it seems that SDL already sets an error handler, which calls the previous error handler, which is the default one that terminates the program on error. (`src/video/x11/SDL_x11video.c::X11_SafetyNetErrHandler()`)

Internally SDL will override this error handler temporarily, when doing its own stuff. (`src/video/x11/SDL_x11video.c::X11_CheckWindowManager()`)

Thus, I guess 2) is the correct way to go.

EDIT:

When omitting `SDL_DestroyWindow()`, `SDL_Quit()` will fail with the same X error.

I also realized that SDL may not anticipate a failed X call, so ignoring the error may not be a good idea, after all.

EDIT2:

I just realized that `SetErrorHandler()` does not require a `display`.

Adding an X error handler that ignores X errors regarding this particular X window seems to work, not sure if it creates new problems unseen.

---

**Is there preferred way to handle this problem?**

---

Version:
SDL2-2.0.9